# Blackberry simulator not connecting with blackberry connector

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to run my app in the blackberry 10 simulator . I have installed blackberry 10 sdk , black berry simulator and added ripple emulator in google chrome.

Now i opened the application in common resources, enabled the ripple and in ripple emulator gave all the information for packaging and launching, like ip of the bb10 simulator and password, the build was success. I could see the folder containg the .bar files.

The problem is it is not launched in the simulator which is in vmware. So i tried with the obtained .bar file through command to run the app. And the error saying timeout couldnt connect came.

Then opened the bb10 connector and it is not connecting automatically, i tried connecting manually . But not happening.

Can anyone help me to solve the following issue.

Comment: This question should be asked in the BlackBerry 10 forums; here, you ask programming questions.

Comment: @IdanAdar, the fact that there are over 6300 android-emulator questions I think it belongs here as well. RubixBrain: try using [BB10 app manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bb10-playbook-app-manager/kmbaalodpmjjhpobkgljnelbpblnikkp?hl=en-US) for google chrome. Try if it works there

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on your workstation? That could interfere.